# build term document matrix from PDF file

Tags: r, pdf, information-retrieval, tm, term-document-matrix

I am trying to build `term document matrix` from one pdf text. When I inspect the `term document matrix`, I get this.

```
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 7245, documents:342)>>
```

The number of document should 1 not 342, and 342 is number of pages in pdf files. 
I've tried use this code using R.

```
pdf_file <- file.path(("Lat/web"), "textpdf.pdf")
text <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))

mytdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list
                         (removeNumbers = TRUE, 
                         removePunctuation = TRUE, 
                         stopwords=stopwords_en, 
                         stemming=TRUE)
)
inspect(mytdm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to collapse the pdf pages into 1 document.

```
pdf_file <- file.path(("Lat/web"), "textpdf.pdf")
text <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
# collapse pdf pages into 1
text <- paste(unlist(text), collapse ="")
.....
rest of code
```

Comment: very very thanks @phiver, its working, thank you again

Comment: @Hilfit19, You are welcome. If you accept the answer your reputation will also increase.